# Content in a forum. Duplicate content

Tags: duplicate-content, forum

I wanted to ask a question about my forum. I wanted to know if a repeated question is asked daily over the course of a year with multiple users asking the same thing or answering the same thing. For example “yes, it would be healthy to eat vegetables daily.” If this has been said 50 times on my forum would it be considered duplicate content ?

Can multiple users sign up and post repeated questions through the year pertaining to the same topic. For example “how much water should I drink?”

Comment: if questions are 15-30 words and copied from another member?

Comment: From [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site): Google almost never penalizes for content duplicated within your own website.  At worst, Google will ignore a page which duplicates another page on your site.   Almost all sites repeat small amounts of text from page to page.   Pages with plenty of unique content won't be hurt by small amounts of duplicated content.